# TestCafe t.eval vs. ClientFunction

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

What is the difference between TestCafes [t.eval()](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/eval.html) function and [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html)?

I've been using TestCafe for a while now and didn't stumble across the eval function until now.

I am curious, but I also have a concrete use case, which is not the subject of this question, but might help me understand the difference between both.
I'd like to do simple page manipulation tasks like hiding elements from my tests code.
The documentation clearly says that ClientFunction should not be used for this: "Do not modify the tested webpage within client functions. Use test actions to interact with the page instead."
Is the eval function suitable for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, they are the same. The difference is that `ClientFunction` creates an instance that can be saved to a variable and then reused several times, while `t.eval` works without saving. Also, `t.eval` is executed immediately, while `ClientFunction` is not - it creates an instance that you need to call explicitly in order to run it.

Comment: Yes, page state manipulation via ClientFunction or the `t.eval` method is not recommended. It leads to the fact that tests stop to fully simulate user behavior. But, technically, they do not have restrictions on altering the page state. It's fine to use them if you cannot achieve the desired outcome with TestCafe actions.